# working with vh unit in CSS

Tags: html, css, viewport-units

I have an element in html that i want it covers all pages.I write below code in CSS:

```
div{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```

but in firefox,chrome and opera , the page is scrolled.i don't have this problem in IE and Microsoft edge.

Comment: This happens if your element contains any margins, padding or even if your html code contains any blank spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

div{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
  <div></div>
```